# Tree-root trust confusion

Tags: active-directory

Ok, this is probably an easy one, but I *could swear* I have read it in one or the other Active Directory related book, and now I just can't get it out of my head even though no other sources seem to confirm it, and it *sounds* unnecessary and wrong. It could easily be from some documentation dating back to very early betas of AD, for all I know.

The statement was that when you create a child domain (say "accounting.france.company.lcl") of a domain (say "france.company.lcl")that is itself already a child domain of the tree-root domain(say "company.lcl"), Active Directory will not only create a two-way transitive trust between these two parent and child domains, but also an automatic two-way transitive trust directly between the downlevel child, and the tree-root 2 steps up. So the trust between the downlevel child domain and the tree-root domain would not only be implicit - transitive through the intermediate direct parent domain - but also more like a shortcut trust.

It would just be nice if someone could wipe this out of my head by a strong statement. :-)

Answer (score 3):

According to [This technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), the default intra-tree trust architecture is rooted and transitive, not full-mesh.

[image]

My trusty copy of Windows 2000 Active Directory by Lowe-Norris does contain some confusing language that could be misconstrued as implying that a full-mesh trust system is set up, Maybe that's where your confusion is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

An AD trust is represented in AD by a TDO (trustedDomain object). If you view the domain partition in ADSIEdit you'll see that a TDO exists for a child domain's direct parent domain and it's child domains (if they exist). You won't see a TDO for any shortcut trusts because they're not automatically created between child domains. The trust path is "vertical".